# Reference std::basic_string specialization of string with custom allocator as a constant object of std::string without overhead?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, casting

Given an object of class `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,my_allocator<char> >`, how would you pass it to a third-party function that expects a constant reference to an object of class `std::string` without making any copies?

What I am thinking is if we assume a stateless allocator, then, theoretically, two types should be exactly the same in runtime. Therefore, one could simply re-interpret cast the type, for example:

```
// my_allocator template is some place else...
typedef std::basic_string< char, std::char_traits<char>,
                           my_allocator<char> > my_string;

void third_party_foo(const std::string &s);

int main()
{
    const my_string str = "Hello, world!";
    third_party_foo(*(const std::string *)&str);
}
```

Given an allocator that has a state (which we can have since C++11), I would assume this is a lot more dangerous since sizes and layout of those classes in runtime could be different. If I am right thus far, let's say that sizes of the object of two classes are the same, in that case I could assume that allocator state fits, say, into some area that would have otherwise been padded, in which case the first approach can work.

How much do I put myself in danger with this approach, practically speaking? Are there any  alternatives that do not carry any runtime overhead (and of course do not require changing third-party interface and/or giving up a string with custom allocator)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. By using a custom allocator, you're using a *different* type from `std::string`. And there's no (legitimate) way in C++ to convert this without a copy. Anything you think *might* work will not be guaranteed by the C++ standard.

So you have to accept that you need a copy.

Comment: Nicol, thanks for the answer. This is pretty much what I though. Given that allocator is of no use in a constant object, this sounds to me like a weakness by design so to speak. I was hoping there is some trick like `rebind` concept that can be used to safely cast the types as with allocators.